# Run Macro after ConEmu is started

Tags: conemu, cmder

Is it possible to ssh login into a server automatically after that I open ConEmu?
I am basically trying to run a macro immediately after that the task loads the command line.

Comment: And what have you tried? https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html

Comment: I haven't tried any. I am trying to understand how do I run a macro (or a set of commands) automatically immediately after the task startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, hardcoding logins/passwords is a bad approach.

Much better would be using [ssh-agent](https://conemu.github.io/en/SshAgent.html).

But, of course, it's possible to use [GuiMacro](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html)
to type anything in the created console.

Well, supposing that `bash.exe` is available through `%PATH%`,
you may create the [Task](https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html)
using the following command:

```
bash.exe -c 'ConEmuC -Silent -GuiMacro Print "login" -GuiMacro Keys Enter -GuiMacro Print "password" -GuiMacro Keys Enter ; ssh your-server'
```

Bash makes me crazy... instead of simple `-GuiMacro Print "login\npassword\n"`
you shall use four `-GuiMacro` blocks... I failed to let bash pass quotes
properly as ConEmuC arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I do this

1. Install Cygwin and Openssh
2. Use a ssh key and authorized key on the server.

Create a .bat file with the code below in it

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin

bash.exe --login -i -c "ssh [username]@[domain] -p [port] -D [port]"
```

Create a ConEmu `Startup` `Tasks`

```
cmd /k RenameTab "MyTabName" & "C:\[path]\MyBatFile.bat"
```

I also pin ConEmu to the TaskBar, and use this task in the `Jump List`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be a simple and clean way to perform a series of commands at once, doing it in one line seems difficult to read. Do you happen to know where I can find the list of console commands I can use and the explanation? For example, what does `-i -c -p -D` mean? Is the order important?

Comment: basically google for: "man bash" and "man ssh". You can also type "man bash" or "man ssh" into your linux terminal and it will bring up a local copy of the manual which explains what the arguments do